# Laravel Eager Loading | Query for specific User

Tags: php, laravel

I have some trouble to display results that are made by a specific user.

With the code below I receive all entries ($restaurantmenue), instead I only need the entries that are made by the specific user. How can I query only for the user that creates the entry?

```
//Restaurant Profile Page
public function showrestaurants($id) {
  $restaurant = User::findOrFail($id);
  //$restaurant->addclick();

  $restaurantmenue = User::with(['articles' => function ($q){
    $q->nowpublished();
  }])->get();

  return view('pages.profile')->withRestaurant($restaurant)->withRestaurantmenue($restaurantmenue);
}
```

nowpublished() Scope in Article.php:

```
public function scopeNowPublished($query) {
  $zero = Carbon::today()->addHours(23)->addMinutes(59)->addSeconds(59);
  $query->whereBetween('published_at',[Carbon::today(),$zero])->orderBy('published_at','desc');
}
```

My View:

```
@foreach($restaurantmenue as $daily)
                  @foreach($daily->articles as $menue)
                    <div class="card card-horizontal">
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-5">
                          <div class="image" style="background-image: url({{asset('images/frontend/profile/profileHero.jpg')}}); background-size: cover; background-position: center center;">
                            <img src="{{asset('images/frontend/profile/profileHero.jpg')}}" alt="..." style="display: none;">
                            <div class="filter filter-azure">
                              <button type="button" class="btn btn-neutral btn-round">
                                  <i class="fa fa-heart"></i> SMÄCKT MIR
                              </button>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-7">
                             <div class="content">
                               <p class="category text-info">
                                    <i class="fa fa-trophy"></i> Best of
                                </p>

                                <a class="card-link" href="#">
                                    <h4 class="title">{{$menue->title}} </h4>
                                </a>
                                <a class="card-link" href="#">
                                    <p class="description">{{$menue->body}}</p>
                                    <br />
                                    {{$menue->price}} €
                                </a>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  @endforeach
                @endforeach
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you should do something like this:

```
$restaurantmenue = User::where('id', $id)->with(['articles' => function ($q) {
    $q->nowpublished();
}])->get();
```